# AWS API Gateway + SQS with more than 256KB of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am integrating AWS API Gateway with AWS SQS.

What would happen if API Gateway receives a payload > 256KB? Can I divert it to S3 somehow?

Answer (score 1):

In this use case, you probably want to use a lambda proxy integration with API gateway.

So, your API Gateway endpoint sends the payload to a lambda function.

The lambda function works out the size of the payload. If it is <256KB you may want to place his onto the queue in SQS via the lambda.

If it is >256kb then you could write this down to s3 via the lambda, and then place a message into your queue with the s3 details. Your worker can then use the message in the queue to grab the data in s3 and process it from there.

Note there is a 10MB payload limit for API Gateway.

AWS provide the following guide on Lambda Proxy Integration with API Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html